# XSLT 2.0 How to change default formatting for numbers?

Tags: xslt, formatting, xslt-2.0, number-formatting

In XSLT 1.0 (using Xalan), outputting the result of:

```
<xsl:variable name="source0" select="number(num3)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$source0"/>
```

was the number spelled out as 2011234. But in XSLT 2.0 (using Saxon), it shows up as 2.011234E6. I want it to always display as 2011234 in the Saxon/2.0 case.

Is there a way to set the default picture string for whenever it outputs a number?

I saw decimal-format, but that just affects picture strings, it doesn't set number formatting. I can't just throw format-number everywhere since then I'd have to check datatypes everywhere and... it would be a mess.

Comment: Don't use floating point unless you want floating point. Get into the habit of declaring the type of your variables (e.g. as="xs:integer"), and using explicit conversions (xs:decimal(), xs:integer()) rather than the number() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to express in XSLT 2.0 (or XSLT 1.0) that every time a number value is output it must be in a "default" format, without ussing `fn:format-number()` or `xsl:decimal-format` or `op:cast` or built-in type constructors. The only way that every number will be consider of some specific type is that a schema has been declared for the input (so it's a PSVI) and you run the transformation with schema-awere processor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...

Wow, that seems crazy. There is a default conversion, obviously, so why not make it possible to adjust that default conversion? What a nuisance. So it requires format-number's showing up all over the place... and now I discover that format-number has serious issues... but that's a different question...

Comment: @taotree: I think that to declare a "default" number format it would be a feature, but I don't think it would be a much desired one like first class function, items pattren matching or nested sequence, as example.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. The number formatting support is minimal, the default format that switches to scientific at 7 digits... the supporting features are insufficient to make settable default formatting all that meaningful anyway.